# Android SearchView bottom line not showing on all devices with AppCompat

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-actionbar-compat

I'm building an app with the AppCompat theme and in the action bar I'm using a SearchView. The problem is that the text field of the SearchView, in some cases, not shows the bottom line as per the AppCompat theme. In this screenshot you can see what I'm talking about:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ka97u.png

Above there's the SearchView without bottom line, and below the same view with the line. This is my `styles.xml`:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="actionOverflowMenuStyle">@style/OverflowMenu</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">#33B5E5</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">#33B5E5</item>
</style>

<style name="OverflowMenu" parent="Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu.Overflow">
    <item name="overlapAnchor">false</item>
</style>
```

And this is a little table of the devices/emulatore i tryied with:

- Emulator API Lvl 14 -> No line
- Emulator API Lvl 16 -> No line
- Samsung Galaxy Note (GT-N8000) API Lvl 16 -> YES
- Emulator API Lvl 18 -> YES
- Samsung Galaxy S4 (GT-I9515) API Lvl 19 -> YES
- Emulator API LVL 21 -> YES

My First tought was something related to API level, but then why my tablet shows the line and the emulator with same API (16) doesn't?